# Cordova app on iOS 9x not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator, ios9

I am testing my cordova app via Xcode simulator on multiple phone types running various versions of 9x through 11x.  The app installs and works as intended on all devices running 10x and 11x but is not working on devices running 9x (specifically 9.3).  On 9x devices, my app splash screen shows up and then the screen goes white.

In Xcode console I get zero errors or warnings - from a console perspective it just looks like a successful install.  However, when trying to access Safari -> Develop -> Simulator - the app is not appearing as running so I can't view anything in Safari.  I have no idea what to look for or what could be causing this.  Any ideas or thoughts as to where/what to look for?  This is consistently happening on any simulator device running 9.3 (5s, 6, 6 plus, 6s, 6s plus)

```
My app is running:
Cordova 4.5.0
Ionic: 1.7.14
cocoapods 1.3.1

And my installed plugins:
cl.rmd.cordova.dialoggps 0.0.2 "DialogGPS"
com.lampa.startapp 0.1.4 "startApp"
com.ludei.webview.plus 2.3.0 "Webview+"
com.peerio.cordova.plugin.carrier 1.0.1 "Carrier"
com.phonegap.plugins.nativesettingsopener 1.0.1 "Native settings"
com.vliesaputra.deviceinformation 1.0.1 "DeviceInformation"
cordova-instagram-plugin 0.5.5 "Instagram"
cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.29.22 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-appavailability 0.4.2 "AppAvailability"
cordova-plugin-appinfo 2.1.2 "AppInfo Plugin"
cordova-plugin-apprate 1.3.0 "AppRate"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.5 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 1.0.7 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-email 1.2.6 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.5.2 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps 1.0.0 "checkGPS"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.24 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.7 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-queries-schemes 0.1.1 "App Queries Strings"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.2.2 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-sim 1.3.3 "SIM"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.5 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-sms-plugin 0.1.11 "Cordova SMS Plugin"
cordova-universal-clipboard 0.1.0 "Clipboard"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.7.1 "Diagnostic"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

On a side note, it would be easy to just ignore 9x and keep my app at 10x/11x, however, nearly 10% of the iOS install base is still running iOS 9x - thats a pretty significant user base to ignore.

Comment: did you end up finding any solution to this?
we are now 3 months on from your post, and I have been testing on ios 9.* devices and having the same result. I'm pretty much feeling the same as you about the non-coverage, but i don't want to roll down either as there are now many more 10 and 11 devices that would have reduced functionality.

Comment: I have not found a solution for this.  It has been frustrating.  Not only not a solution, but no one has commented on it at all.  You are the first to comment and the only other indication that the issue is not just isolated to me.  What plugins and versions are you running...maybe we can figure this out by comparing installs.

Comment: do you have a package.json you could add also, 
depending on how your building the app, eg im using ionic, which uses the cordova-ios and cordova-android packages from npm, these have hard limited targets. im using cordova-ios 4.5.4 which doesnt support anything before 10.

Comment: I am using cordova 4.5.0.  I wasn't aware of 4.5.4 not supporting pre 10x iOS.  Why on earth would they do that...no backward comparability?!  Doesn't make sense to me.  However...if you are using 4.5.4 AND 4.5.4 doesn't support pre 10x iOS - wouldn't it be safe to assume that that is the source of your issue?  That being said, we are on two different version and still experiencing the same problem...hopefully then we can still track down the problem.  My packages and install info is all listed above.